# Can I use multiple CDN with WP Fastest Cache on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, cdn, cloudflare

So I have set 3 CDNs at my WP Fastest Cache:
Cloudflare, Photon (Jetpack) and KeyCDN. Are all those 3 active all the time? Or only the last one added is being used? Is there a logic to use such combination?